# unable to print the label with spaces in zebra print barcoder

Tags: php, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am unable to print the total word it having spaces.using zebraGK420d Printer.

here the code is

```
$barcode_ZPL_code="^XA4
^FO 80,50^AD,25^FDTest Message^FS 
^FO80,130^AD^BY2
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^MD10
^FDLTX81309-3(3)-COK^FS
^FO80,280^AF^FDTest Message Display^FS 
^XZ";
```

unable to print the full name "Test Message".Only printing the word"Test". and If i given commas(,) also it should taken but it label format is not correct like it displays 
**SHOP,212- (5spaces) CENTER MALL,(5spaces)     -MAIN- ROAD** . Please give the solution for this one.Thanks

Comment: What width labels are you using? What is your print width set to? Try setting the print width by adding this after the ^XA  :  ^PW576

Comment: and get rid of the '4' after the ^XA

Comment: i removed 4 and checked. but its not working

Answer (score 1):

A work around is replacing the space characters with the ZPL escape code "_20" where the number 20 is the hex representation of the space character.

The following describes this method in detail and provides the Zebra documentation reference.

[How to print escape codes in ZPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821629/how-to-print-a-tilde-in-zebra-programming-language-zpl)