# &nbsp; is getting replaced with á on labels

Tags: html, zebra-printers

I have the following code

```
<td colspan="@missingGridColumnCount">**&nbsp;<span translate="MissingItems">.MissingInstruments</span>&nbsp;**</td>
```

This prints correctly through the browser but when I print to my Zebra printer, I get the following on the label:

```
**_áMissing Items_á**
```

I have looked through Zebra Label documentation but cannot find a way to convert this or accept the `&nbsp;` for the labels.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266331/unable-to-print-the-label-with-spaces-in-zebra-print-barcoder), it might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue.

The probable chain of events is this:

- The browser is rendering the `&nbsp;` entity into the Unicode code point "U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE".
- This is being encoded in UTF-8, as the sequence of bytes `C2 A0`.
- These bytes are being interpreted by the Zebra printer according to [Code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), where `C2` is mapped to "┴" (U+2534 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND HORIZONTAL) and `A0` to "á" (U+00E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE).

In code page 850, a non-breaking space is represented by the byte `FF`.

You may be able to tell the whatever is interpreting the HTML to use Code page 850 instead of UTF-8, and it will send the byte sequences the printer is expecting. You will need to make sure your input doesn't contain any literal UTF-8 - escape all non-ASCII characters as HTML entities.

Otherwise, you will need to substitute byte-wise before sending to the printer, or encode in some other way.