# How to print caret(^) character in Zebra Programming Language?

Tags: escaping, zpl-ii

Using version: `ZPL2`.

Format prefix: `^`.

Can someone please help how to print caret(`^`) character using ZPL II. Either we need some escape sequence or any other way of printing this Format Prefix(`^`) as a normal character.

Note: Don't want to change the format prefix(`^`) to some other character.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use ^FH before your ^FD and then use the hex value of the caret : _5E

```
^XA
^FO100,100
^AD^FH
^FDCaret _5e used for HEX^FS
^XZ
```

See also : [How to print a tilde (~) in Zebra Programming Language (ZPL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821629/how-to-print-a-tilde-in-zebra-programming-language-zpl)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to change format prefix of ZPL code which is ^ into different one ex. ¬ using ^CC. After print command, reverse the change back to ^.

`^XA
^CC¬
¬FO30,20¬FD_AB534^H¬FS
¬CC^
^XZ`

The ^FH and _5e solution is also good but will not work in all cases.
If you use ^FH command it will convert everything which appear to be hex value

example - you want to print wifi password which is: _AB534^H.
Normally you would use code:

`^XA
^FO50,50
^FD_AB534^H^FS
^XZ`

this code will print only:_AB534

with ^FH command and replacing ^ with _5E  will look like:

`^XA
^FO50,50
^FH^FD_AB534_5EH^FS
^XZ`

it prints:  ½534^H

Password is different than _AB534^H. this is because ^FH reads _AB as a HEX value and converts it as well

using this code:

`^XA
^CC¬
¬FO30,20¬FD_AB534^H¬FS
¬CC^
^XZ`

output is:_AB534^H

sign ¬ can not be entered simply from keyboard (without alt+ combination) so will not be used in wifi passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to escape "_" as "_5f" and then escape "^" as "_5e".  This protects against accidental decoding of a string already containing "_" without encoding every single character in ^FD, ^FV or ^SN commands.

In c#, this would be:

```
return value.Replace("_", "_5f").Replace("^", "_5e");
```

This is not the most efficient code, but is concise.